# How did Google manage to crawl my 403 pages?

Tags: web-crawlers, security, googlebot

I had a couple private files in a directory on my school folder. You could see that the files existed by going to myschool.edu/myusername/myfolder, but trying to access the files themselves via myschool.edu/myusername/myfolder/myfile.html returns a 403 error.

And yet Google somehow managed to grab the contents of those private files and store them in its cache! How is this possible? [I've since removed those files, so I'm just curious how Google managed to do this.]

Comment: This belongs on Webmasters

Answer (score 5):

The most probable reason is that the pages won't return a 403 header.

You can check that using the Web Developer Toolbar in Firefox or Chrome. The tool is located under "Information" -> "View Response Headers".

Also, the way I create my error pages is:

1. I create some dummy error page. Let's say **403.php**.
2. I create an actual error page. For example **error403.php**.
3. On the dummy error page, I put the following code: `<?php header("Location: /error403.php",TRUE,301); ?>`
4. In my .htaccess, I put the following:

   `Options -Indexes`

   `ErrorDocument 403 /403.php`

This adds all the redirects in a proper way and makes me sure I'm getting some juice from my error pages.

This can actually be extended in an extremely cool way if your website has a search engine which uses GET requests.